# Can we add more then one @RemoteAction in a single apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, b2b-commerce

When I add the second RemoteAction Function in my apex class then it will give me an error on vf page.
I am using B2B package and it gives me site Error
And When I remove the @RemoteAction annotation from the second method in apex then it works fine.

Apex class :-

```
@RemoteAction 
global static String createNewCoupon(string newCouponBalance, Decimal currentRewardPoins, String accId){
    if(String.isNotBlank(newCouponBalance)){
        if(Decimal.valueOf(newCouponBalance) < currentRewardPoins){
            ccrz__E_Coupon__c coupon = new ccrz__E_Coupon__c();
            coupon.ccrz__CouponName__c = 'Online Store Credit For ' + newCouponBalance;
            Integer len = 12;
            Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
            String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
            String pwd = key.substring(0,len);
            coupon.ccrz__CouponCode__c = pwd;
            coupon.ccrz__DiscountAmount__c = Decimal.valueOf(newCouponBalance);
            coupon.ccrz__DiscountType__c = 'Absolute';
            coupon.Account__c = accId;
            coupon.ccrz__MaxUse__c = 1;
            coupon.ccrz__TotalUsed__c = 0;
            coupon.ccrz__Storefront__c = 'HFStorefront';
            coupon.ccrz__RuleType__c = 'CartTotal';
            coupon.Is_Taxable__c = true;

            insert coupon; 
            updateAccountRewardBalance(accId,newCouponBalance);
        }else{
            return 'You dont have enough points please contact your adminstrator';
        }
    }
    return 'Success';
}
```

Second Function

```
@RemoteAction public static String combineCoupons(String couponCode){
    List<String> couponCodeList = couponCode.split(',');
    Id accId; 
    accId = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM user WHERE Id =: Userinfo.getUserId()].AccountId;

    System.debug('accId'+accId);
    System.debug('couponCodeList>>>'+couponCodeList);
    //System.assert(false, accId);
    Decimal amount=0;
    List<ccrz__E_Coupon__c> couponListToUpdate = new List<ccrz__E_Coupon__c>();
    List<ccrz__E_Coupon__c> couponList = [Select id,ccrz__DiscountAmount__c ,ccrz__TotalUsed__c,ccrz__MaxUse__c from ccrz__E_Coupon__c where ccrz__CouponCode__c IN:couponCodeList AND ccrz__MaxUse__c>0];
    System.debug('couponList>>>'+couponList);
    if(couponList.size()==couponCodeList.size()){
        for(ccrz__E_Coupon__c couponAmount:couponList){
            amount= amount + couponAmount.ccrz__DiscountAmount__c;
        }
        System.debug('amount'+amount);
        for(ccrz__E_Coupon__c updateCoupon:couponList){
            ccrz__E_Coupon__c c=new ccrz__E_Coupon__c(); 
            c.id = updateCoupon.id;
            c.ccrz__MaxUse__c = updateCoupon.ccrz__MaxUse__c - 1;
            couponListToUpdate.add(c);
        }
        System.debug('couponListToUpdate......'+couponListToUpdate);
        if(couponListToUpdate.size()>0){
            update couponListToUpdate;
        }
        ccrz__E_Coupon__c coupon = new ccrz__E_Coupon__c();
            coupon.ccrz__CouponName__c = 'Online Store Credit For ' + amount;
            Integer len = 12;
            Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
            String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
            String pwd = key.substring(0,len);
            coupon.ccrz__CouponCode__c = pwd;
            coupon.ccrz__DiscountAmount__c = amount;
            coupon.ccrz__DiscountType__c = 'Absolute';
            coupon.Account__c = accId;
            coupon.ccrz__MaxUse__c = 1;
            coupon.ccrz__TotalUsed__c = 0;
            coupon.ccrz__Storefront__c = 'HFStorefront';
            coupon.ccrz__RuleType__c = 'CartTotal';
            coupon.Is_Taxable__c = true;
            System.debug('coupon>>>>>>>'+coupon);
            insert coupon; 
        return 'Success';
    }
    else{
        return 'Failed! Try again';
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my JS from where I am calling the functions

```
function validateFields(){
    newCouponBalance = $('.newBalance').val();
    if(newCouponBalance == null || newCouponBalance == '' || newCouponBalance == undefined) {
        $('#errorMsg').html('<strong>Error!</strong> You must enter the Coupon Balance.');
        $('#errorMsg').show();
        return false;
    }
    var accId = '{!accId}';
    $('#savingBtnDiv').show();
    $('#savingBtn').show();
    $('#saveBtnDiv, #cancelBtnDiv, #cancelBtnDiv1').hide();

    console.log(' <<newCouponBalance >>'+ newCouponBalance);
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.LoyaltyPointsController.createNewCoupon}',
        newCouponBalance, {!LoyaltyPointBalance}, accId,
        function(result, event){
            console.log()
            if (event.status) {
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                if(result != 'Success'){
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#errorMsg').html('<strong>' + result +'</strong>');
                    $('#errorMsg').show();  

                    $('#savingBtnDiv').hide();
                    $('#savingBtn').hide();
                    $('#saveBtnDiv, #cancelBtnDiv, #cancelBtnDiv1').show();

                    return false; 
                }
                refreshPage();
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

            } else {

            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );

}
function combineCoupon(){ 
    couponCodesString = combined_coupons.toString();
    console.log(couponCodesString);
    if(couponCodesString == null || couponCodesString == '' || couponCodesString == undefined) {
        $('#errorMsg').html('<strong>Error!</strong> You must select atleast two coupon.');
        $('#errorMsg').show();
        return false;
    }

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction( 
        '{!$RemoteAction.LoyaltyPointsController.combineCoupons}',
        couponCodesString,
        function(result, event){
            console.log('result>>>',result);
            if (event.status) {
                alert('event.status>>>',event.status);
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                if(result != 'Success'){
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#errorMsg').html('<strong>' + result +'</strong>');
                    $('#errorMsg').show();  

                    $('#savingBtnDiv').hide();
                    $('#savingBtn').hide();
                    $('#saveBtnDiv, #cancelBtnDiv, #cancelBtnDiv1').show();

                    return false; 
                }
                refreshPage();
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {

            } else {

            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    ); 

}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? You can add as many RemoteAction methods to your class as you want.